# Copy Woocommerce product variations from one products to others mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for any way to copy attributes and variations from one product to others ? If there is any plugin which can help or any way to do this using phpmyadmin / mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved by using Advance WooCommerce Bulk Editor